# User mapping problem during deployment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a development machine with a new database I have designed. The server has a login L1 and the database has a user U1. L1 is mapped to M1 and tables have permissions set up for U1. Authentication is SQL Server authentication. I wanted to fully backup the database and restore to the production server so that I could start to use it in production.

I had a problem with user U1: I could not map it to any login on the production server. So I could not use U1 with any login. Is this correct behavior?

Comment: 'I could not map it to any login' - why?  Is there a login user missing or what?

Comment: Well the restored database on the production server has a user U1 and tables have permissions set for this user. But I cant map a login to this user OR I don't know how to.

Comment: use DB
ALTER USER U1  
 WITH 
      NAME = U1 ,
     LOGIN = L1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a login on the prod server as when you restore the backup to PROD server, you are having an orphaned user.

So steps are :

- [Create Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) using SID option (if you are just having 1 login to map). Else use [sp_help_revlogin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992)
- You can use **SID** from [sys.database_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx) where `type_desc = SQL_USER` (since you mentioned you are using SQL Login).
- Then run ALTER USER as below :

  ```
  USE [DatabaseName]
  go
  ALTER USER [UserName]
  WITH LOGIN = [UserName]
  ```

Note: [sp_change_users_login](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx) is deprecated.